# Closed form for the sum $\sum_{a=1}^{b} a^3\cdot (b \bmod a)$

Tags: number-theory, summation, modular-arithmetic, closed-form

How can we simplify 
$\sum_{a=1}^{b} a^3\cdot (b \mod a)$?
For $a \ge \frac{b+1}{2} $ to $a = b$ it reduces to $$\sum_{a\ge \frac{b+1}{2}}^{b}a^3\cdot (b-a)=b\cdot\sum_{a\ge \frac{b+1}{2}}^{b}a^3-\sum_{a\ge \frac{b+1}{2}}^{b}a^4$$
but getting no idea in $a= 1$ to $a \le \frac{b}{2}$ ?

Comment: I cannot read the formulas. You may find the fact that $1^3+2^3+\cdots+n^3=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$ useful.

Comment: do you mean $$\sum\limits_{a=1}^b a^3\left(b \pmod a\right)$$ ?

Comment: yes @ganeshie8 .. sorry i coudnt write it properly

Comment: No worries :) this looks hard, but I'll give it a try

Comment: i think this would not reduce to simple formula .. but should be reduced into simpler parts

Comment: You have below so far $$\sum\limits_{a=\lfloor b/2\rfloor +1}^b a^3\left(b \pmod a\right) =  b\sum\limits_{a=\lfloor b/2\rfloor +1}^{b}a^3 -  \sum\limits_{a=\lfloor b/2\rfloor +1}^{b}a^4 $$

Comment: That looks wrong. For $b=5$ it gives 118 compared to 126 for the original.

Comment: I don't think there is a simple formula. I calculated the first few terms: $0,0,8,27,126,253,693,1204,2418,3801$ and oeis.org did not recognize it.